# What are the target drop zones in rich:dragSupport?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Can somebody give me a list of values drop zones?

Answer (score 0):

Target for `rich:dragSupport` is `rich:dropSupport`. More details here: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dragSupport.jsf?c=dropSupport&tab=usage